# How can I hide the MacBook name and path name in terminal initial line?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

When I run terminal I see my username and the path

```
Marc-MacBook-Air:~ Marc$
```

Can I change it? Iso how can I change it into?

```
Marc$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `PS1` environment variable in your `.bashrc`.

To do this, do `nano .bashrc` or `vi .bashrc` in your home folder based on which text editor you like to use.

Add a new line to your .bashrc which reads `export PS1="\u$ "`, save your file, and restart Terminal.

Et voila! Your terminal prompt should now read:

```
Marc$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `PS1` variable value to something that works for you. You can open up the Terminal and simply enter stuff like this:

```
PS1='\u$ '
```

And when you hit <kbd>Return</kbd> the change will immediately take effect. Test like crazy this way—and even play around with online tools like this “[`>_ .bashrc PS1 generator`](http://bashrcgenerator.com)” to get your prompt looking the way you would like it to look.

Then, when you are done, you can edit your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file to add this line right at the top:

```
PS1='\u$ '
```

You can use Nano to edit the file like this:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Or:

```
nano .bashrc
```

For more details, look at the “[The Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html)” found here as well as this “[Customizing Your Bash Command Prompt](https://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/)” blog post on SuperUser found here.